# How do I write an Euler function in Mathematica?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I programmed a Euler function but misread the instructions, so now I have to make a new one, but I can't figure it out.

I have made the following automatic Euler function.

```
f[x_, y_] := -x y^2;
x0 = 0;
y0 = 2;
xend = 2;
steps = 20;
h = (xend - x0)/steps // N;
x = x0;
y = y0;
eulerlist = {{x, y}};
For[i = 1, i <= steps, y = f[x, y]*h + y;
  x = x + h;
  eulerlist = Append[eulerlist, {x, y}];
  i++
]
Print[eulerlist]
```

But it just generates the list I have specified.

I would like to  have a Euler function which is able to generate this form:

```
Euler[y, 2, -x y^2, {x, 0, 2}, 20]
```

I don't seem to get any further.

Comment: Hmm... why did this get 4 downvotes? Did I miss something?

Comment: Please don't delete the code in the question after you've gotten your answer.

Comment: Please don't edit the title to something meaningless and add `(Solved)`. We know it is solved because you have an answer and you have accepted it.

Comment: @yoda - the original version of the question was almost incomprehensible.

Comment: @yoda strange, I edited the body but didn't do anything with the title. Yet, I see a change in the title attributed to me. I suppose there were two edits close to each other or so.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I figured... sometimes changes made in the grace period by the OP (which are not tracked) get attributed to the subsequent editor (in this case, you) if their edit times overlapped. Besides, I didn't expect that title from you, so that also pointed to a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what you are asking, but if what you want is to be able to input

```
Euler[y, 2, -x y^2, {x, 0, 2}, 20]
```

and get

```
{{0,2},{0.1,2.},{0.2,1.96},{0.3,1.88317},{0.4,1.77678},{0.5,1.6505},{0.6,1.51429},{0.7,1.37671},{0.8,1.24404},{0.9,1.12023},{1.,1.00728},{1.1,0.905822},{1.2,0.815565},{1.3,0.735748},{1.4,0.665376},{1.5,0.603394},{1.6,0.548781},{1.7,0.500596},{1.8,0.457994},{1.9,0.420238},{2.,0.386684}}
```

Then you need to write a function definition like this:

```
Euler[y0_, f_, {x0_, xend_}, steps_Integer?Positive] := (* body *)
```

Notice the underscores to denote patterns, the `:=` to denote delayed evaluation and the pattern specification `Integer?Positive`.

As for the body of the function -- oh my goodness could you have picked a less Mathematica-style approach? Perhaps not. Procedural loops and `Append` are almost never the best way to do anything in Mathematica.

Here is a better solution.

```
Euler[y_, y0_, f_, {x_, x0_, xend_}, steps_Integer?Positive] :=
 With[{h = N[(xend - x0)/steps], ff = Function[{x, y}, f]}, 
  NestList[{#[[1]] + h, ff[#[[1]], #[[2]]]*h + #[[2]]} &, {x0, y0}, 
   steps]]

Euler[y, 2, -x y^2, {x, 0, 2}, 20]

 {{0, 2}, {0.1, 2.}, {0.2, 1.96}, {0.3, 1.88317}, {0.4, 
  1.77678}, {0.5, 1.6505}, {0.6, 1.51429}, {0.7, 1.37671}, {0.8, 
  1.24404}, {0.9, 1.12023}, {1., 1.00728}, {1.1, 0.905822}, {1.2, 
  0.815565}, {1.3, 0.735748}, {1.4, 0.665376}, {1.5, 0.603394}, {1.6, 
  0.548781}, {1.7, 0.500596}, {1.8, 0.457994}, {1.9, 0.420238}, {2., 
  0.386684}}
```

If you want something that *outputs* `Euler[y, 2, -x y^2, {x, 0, 2}, 20]`, then typing it into the notebook is the quickest method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. i want to type exactly "Euler[y, 2, -x y^2, {x, 0, 2}, 20]", and no #, because the Euler[INPUT] should be different at anytime.

Comment: what's going on with `ff = Function[{x, y}, f]`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - The OP wanted to be able to type `-x y^2` not a pure function in the function call. So to put it in the `NestList` definition, you need to convert it to a pure function, defined over the symbolic variables passed in the function call (in this case `x` and `y`). So `Euler[p, 2, -q p^2, {q, 0, 2}, 20]` gives the same result. Does that clarify?

Comment: If you want to implant a Nestwhilelist, what should you do then?

Comment: @user1098185 the innards of the function would look very similar if you wanted to use `NestWhileList` or `FixedPointList` to iterate to convergence. I leave that as an exercise for you because I am at work.